# Unable to connect an android client to a server on the same LAN with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

lately I've been trying to deepen the networking on Unity Engine by creating a 2D game that uses a LAN connection. Using the same host (computer) both as a server and as a client no problems arise, everything happens when I try to connect an android device to the server (always on the same connection). Basically I tried to check the traffic between server and client with whireshark, the device actually sends the connection request, but the server is unable to connect the client. (no errors of any kind are returned).

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked firewall? What port are you using for the connection?

Comment: i'm using the 7777

Comment: And how are you connecting, what ips do they have. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, unity cannot accept socket from other devices in editor mode.
The code must be compiled in a executable application.

Thanks to all.